# Python loop over stdout of subprocess in chunks?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have been iterating over the sdtout of my subprocess line by line. I was advised to do it in chunks instead. Can anyone show me how to do that please?

Line by line:

```
ffmpeg_sb = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegcmd, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for stdout_line in iter(ffmpeg_sb.stdout.readline, ""):
    yield stdout_line
```

My attempt at chunks:

```
ffmpeg_sb = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegcmd, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for chunk in ffmpeg_sb.stdout.read(1024):
    yield chunk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    chunk = ffmpeg_sb.stdout.read(1024)
    if len(chunk) == 0:
        break
    yield chunk
```